# VB.NET webbrowser script errors

Tags: javascript, vb.net, webbrowser-control

Recently I was able to load javascript in webbrowser before downloading source with this code:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.Window.DomWindow.execscript("text/JavaScript")

    Dim MSDNpage2 As String = WebBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerHtml

    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("e:\msdn2.txt", MSDNpage2, True)

    RichTextBox6.Text = MSDNpage2
```

Unfortunately, the first line causes a browser error. The following code:

```
WebBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True
```

I turn off the notifications, but in this case, the source does not link one I care about. Therefore I ask for your help in solving this problem. I thought that automatic clicking on the 'no' could help, but I could not locate the process responsible for displaying a message.

Comment: [execScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536420%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) takes 2 arguments which is probably why it's giving an error.

Comment: my answer does not fit here

Answer (score 0):

I don't known how to set attributes, when i've got no error, then code is looks like this:

```
    <DIV id=serialInfoBox>
<DIV class=l>
<DIV class=progressBar>
<DIV class=o>
<DIV style="WIDTH: 0px" class=i></DIV></DIV></DIV><HGROUP>
<H2><A href="serial,stargate-universe.html">SGU Stargate Universe</A></H2></HGROUP></DIV>
<DIV class=r><IMG src="/static/serials/stargate-universe_small.jpg"> </DIV></DIV>
<DIV id=player>
<DIV id=player_2 hash="wZlV90mq4I3LgyGB6WGIgyKJvMzHhS2EvAGqhWmI25JIRMyrXIUnjAmAeIKJZqQJcIGBV1HInuKLuS2LnS1ZHWTMDqGrBk0FF9FAPSxMvuSJnAxLjZxHXy1IdSzEiSHJ1W1M" jQuery110007841996969566763="5"></DIV>
<DIV class=clearfix></DIV></DIV></DIV>
<DIV id=underPlayer><A class=l href="odcinek,stargate-universe,lost,s01e15.html">poprzedni odcinek</A> <A class=c watched="0" jQuery110007841996969566763="19">zaznacz jako obejrzane</A> <A class=r href="odcinek,stargate-universe,pain,s01e17.html">następny odcinek</A> </DIV>
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#langs li').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#players li').hide();
                $('#players li.'+$(this).attr('id')).show();
                $('#langs li').removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');
            });

            $('#player_2').click(function(e) {
                $.post("getVideo.html", {hash: $(this).attr('hash')}, function(data) {
                    $('#player').css('background','#000').css('text-align','center');
                    $('#player').html(data);
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: $("#player").offset().top-27
                    }, 1000);
                });
            });

            $('#players a.switcher').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.post("getVideo.html", {hash: $(this).parent().attr('hash')}, function(data) {
                    $('#player').html(data);
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: $("#player").offset().top-27
                    }, 1000);
                });

            });

            $(document).on('click','a.tup',function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var c_id = $(this).parent().attr('cid');
                $.post("commentVote.html",{cid: c_id, mode: "up"}, function(data) {
                    if (data >= 0) {
                        $('#cid'+c_id+' span').removeClass('red').removeClass('green').addClass('green');
                        data = '+'+data;
                    } else {
                        $('#cid'+c_id+' span').removeClass('red').removeClass('green').addClass('red');
                    }
                    $('#cid'+c_id+' span').html(data);
                    $('#cid'+c_id+' .tup').remove();
                    $('#cid'+c_id+' .tdown').remove();
                }) ;
            });
            $(document).on('click','a.tdown',function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var c_id = $(this).parent().attr('cid');
                $.post("commentVote.html",{cid: c_id, mode: "down"}, function(data) {
                    if (data >= 0) {
                        $('#cid'+c_id+' span').removeClass('red').removeClass('green').addClass('green');
                        data = '+'+data;
                    } else {
                        $('#cid'+c_id+' span').removeClass('red').removeClass('green').addClass('red');
                    }
                    $('#cid'+c_id+' span').html(data);
                    $('#cid'+c_id+' .tup').remove();
                    $('#cid'+c_id+' .tdown').remove();
                }) ;
            });


            $('#underPlayer .c').bind('click', function() {
                var el = $(this);
                    if ($(this).attr('watched') == 0) {

                        $.ajax({type: "POST", url: "/reports,seen.html",timeout: 10000,data: "user=1075505&ep=38361", success: function(data) {
                                if (data == 1) {
                                    el.html('oznacz jako nieobejrzane').attr('watched','1');
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        $.ajax({type: "POST", url: "/reports,seen.html",timeout: 10000,data: "user=1075505&rem=1&ep=38361", success: function(data) {
                            if (data == 1) {
                                el.html('zaznacz jako obejrzane').attr('watched','0');
                            }
                        }
                        });
                    }
                return false;
            });

        })
    </SCRIPT>
```

and there is no link I need, but when there is my link, then i've got an error and code looks like this:

```
    <DIV id=serialInfoBox>
    <DIV class=l>
    <DIV class=progressBar>
    <DIV class=o>
    <DIV style="WIDTH: 0px" class=i></DIV></DIV></DIV><HGROUP>
    <H2><A href="serial,stargate-universe.html">SGU Stargate Universe</A></H2></HGROUP></DIV>
    <DIV class=r><IMG src="/static/serials/stargate-universe_small.jpg"> </DIV></DIV>
    <DIV style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; BACKGROUND: #000" id=player>
    <DIV style="POSITION: relative; WIDTH: 750px">
    <DIV style="Z-INDEX: 0; TEXT-ALIGN: center; WIDTH: 750px; BACKGROUND: #000; COLOR: #fff">
    <DIV class=embed>
    <DIV style="Z-INDEX: 0; POSITION: relative; WIDTH: 750px; HEIGHT: 429px; CLEAR: both"><SPAN id=aeceedb4c2667cf66b0cfe9780811fa6></SPAN></DIV>
    <SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="http://premium.iitv.info/static/player/flowplayer-3.2.11.min.js"></SCRIPT>

    <SCRIPT type=text/javascript>
                        $(document).ready( function(){
                            $f("aeceedb4c2667cf66b0cfe9780811fa6", "http://premium.iitv.info/static/player/flowplayer.commercial-3.2.15.swf", {
                                key: '#$3f90d28e7547ada6c98',
                                clip: {
here is url: --->                                    url: 'http://stream.streamo.tv/?scode=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',
                                    provider: 'lighttpd',
                                    scaling: 'fit',
                                    backgroundGradient: 'none',
                                    autoPlay: false,
                                    autoBuffering: false
                                },
                                canvas: {
                                    backgroundColor:'#000',
                                    backgroundGradient: 'none'
                                },
                                plugins: {
                                    lighttpd: {
                                        url: 'flowplayer.pseudostreaming-3.2.11.swf',
                                                                            queryString: escape('?start=${start}')
                                                                        },
                                    controls: {
                                        url: 'flowplayer.controls-3.2.14.swf',
                                        autoHide: 'always'
                                    }
                                                                }
                            });
                        });
                    </SCRIPT>
```

Comment: How exactly does this relate to your original question...?

Comment: you asked me to "takes 2 arguments" so i've test it and now i telling you, that when there is no error, there is also no link probably becouse i doing something wrong. I just showing you what i've got in both cases

Comment: What I meant was that `WebBrowser1.Document.Window.DomWindow.execscript("text/JavaScript")` is going to give you an error because `execScript` takes *2* arguments. You're only giving it one. You should do something like `WebBrowser1.Document.Window.DomWindow.execscript("<JAVASCRIPT YOU WANT TO EXEC>", "JavaScript")`

Comment: Okay, I mean, I'm not sure what exactly should I enter there, because I have never done this before, and how to write programs I learn myself and this is actually my hobby not a job.

Comment: That's fine, you just need to be clearer on what the actual problem is. What are you trying to achieve? You said it was working and now it isn't -- what changes did you make that broke it and why did you make those changes? More specifically, what is the first line in your original question supposed to do and what do you think will happen if you just delete it?

Comment: I know how to make it work, but I have no idea how to get rid of an error ... The only thing I changed is the value of such WebBrowser1.Document.Window.DomWindow.execscript ("text", "JavaScript")
but whatever combination, I always getting the same result as above

Comment: Delete that line. It's (probably) the cause of your error and either way, it's not doing anything useful.

Comment: no, becouse without this line i have no url in source, this line is responsible to execute dynamic part of html source before i will take it to textbox. And url is only reason why i downloading this source...